Nginx HTTP Errors won't be logged with custom error page setup
so I created a sort of advanced nginx setup with a vhosts.conf file which redirect errors to a php file. This PHP File then Display a Beautiful Error Page.
When Checking the Webserver Logs, nothing shows up when an actual error is hit, when visiting the error.php file manually, logs with statuscode of 200 do show up. However, i'd like to have actual errors with their respective statuscode logged as well before they are passed to the error.php file.
Here my vhosts.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name genefit.cc www.genefit.cc;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.htm index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~* /(phpinfo\.php|php_info\.php|info\.php|_profiler/phpinfo\.php|\.ht) {
        deny all;
    }

    # Allow POST on specific endpoints
    location ~* ^/(example1/|example2/|example3/|example4/|example5/|example6/)$ {
        if ($request_method !~ ^(POST|GET)$) {
            return 405;
        }
    }

    # Block requests from certain user agents
    # Restrict methods other than GET and provide a 405 error for other locations
    location / {
        # Block User-Agents from Debugging Utilities/Not real Browsers
        if ($http_user_agent ~* (HTTrack|wget|curl|Python)) {
            return 418;
        }

        # Block by referer header
        if ($http_referer ~* "reqbin\.com") {
            return 418;
        }

        # Block by host header
        if ($http_host ~* "httpbin\.org") {
            return 403;
        }
        # Block every request Method other than GET
        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET)$) {
            return 405;
        }
    }

    # Block access to hidden files with custom error code
    location ~ /\. {
        return 444;
    }

    # Error page configuration
    error_page 403 404 405 418 444 500 /error.php?code=$status;

    location ~ /error.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        root /var/www/html/;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        fastcgi_pass genefit.cc:9000;
        fastcgi_index error.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass genefit.cc:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }
}

Here the log output:
172.18.0.2 -  05/Aug/2024:12:33:47 +0000 "GET /error.php" 200
172.18.0.2 -  05/Aug/2024:12:34:12 +0000 "GET /error.php" 200
172.18.0.2 -  05/Aug/2024:12:34:12 +0000 "GET /error.php" 200
172.18.0.2 -  05/Aug/2024:12:48:35 +0000 "GET /error.php" 200
172.18.0.2 -  05/Aug/2024:12:53:15 +0000 "GET /error.php" 200

I've explained that above already, esenteally i want to have errors logged in the container logs before they are passed to the error.php file. Additionally, it would be nice to see the actual IP from which the requests come from, currently it only show the internal IP of the docker network.
